# Web2py on apache2 is slow

Tags: apache, apache2, web2py

I have two servers, both are linux same configuration (OS and hardware).

I have a program running in PHP in one server and it is very fast is loading the data.

I have web2py running in an different server, it is very slow.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two servers, both are linux same configuration (OS and
>   hardware).

What configuration? what hardware?

> I have a program running in PHP in one server and it is very fast is
>   loading the data.

What amount of data? what database?
What is the purpose of the program?

> I have web2py running in an different server, it is very slow.

What is different on this server? What do you mean by "slow"?

Then my first advice would be to add the following line in a view file:

```
{{=response.toolbar()}}
```

It will show you useful information about request, response, session and db queries timing.
Then you could precise your question to give us more specific examples...